# ChatGPT will not communicate correctly using Javascript API and whatsapp-web.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api, chatgpt-api, whatsapi

The issue I'm having is that ChatGPT gives weird responses when you give it normal information. You can copy my code if you want to try this out yourself, initialise with node and install these packages:

```
npm i qrcode-terminal
npm i child_process
npm i canvas
npm i whatsapp-web.js
npm i openai
```

You can start the chat by typing `!chat` and stop it using `!chat stop`

This is my code: (don't worry about the random commands)

```js
    const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
    const { exec } = require('child_process');
    const { createCanvas } = require('canvas');
    const { Client, LocalAuth, MessageMedia, Buttons, List } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
    
    const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
    require('dotenv').config()
    
    const configuration = new Configuration({
      apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
    });
    const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
    
    const client = new Client({
        authStrategy: new LocalAuth()
    });
    
    client.on('qr', qr => {
        qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});
    });
    
    client.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('Client is ready!');
    });
    
    smp = false
    chatting = false
    
    client.on('message', async message => {
        const content = message.body.toLowerCase()
        commandCount = 0
        if (content.includes("!chat stop")) {
            chatting = false
            console.log("chat stop")
        }
        if (chatting) {
            console.log("\""+content+"\"")
            const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
                model: "text-davinci-003",
                prompt: content,
                max_tokens:4000
            });
            console.log(completion)
            message.reply(completion.data.choices[0].text);
        }
        if (!chatting) {
            if (content.includes("SMP")) {
                if (content.includes("start")) {
                    commandCount += 1
                    message.reply('The SMP Server is attempting to start. Please wait a minute or two for the SMP to start. This may not work if player @GoldenD60 is currently playing a game.');
                    smp = true
                    exec('start.bat',
                        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                            console.log(stdout);
                            console.log(stderr);
                            if (error !== null) {
                                console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
                            }
                        });
                }
                if (content.includes("stop")) {
                    commandCount += 1
                    message.reply('The SMP Server is attempting to stop...');
                    smp = false
                    exec('stop.bat',
                        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                            console.log(stdout);
                            console.log(stderr);
                            if (error !== null) {
                                console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
                            }
                        });
                }
            }
            if ((content.includes("give") || content.includes("send")) && content.includes("cat")) {
                client.sendMessage(message.from, await MessageMedia.fromUrl("https://cataas.com/cat", {unsafeMime: true}), {caption: 'OK, here is a photo of a cat.'})
            }
            if ((content.includes("give") || content.includes("send")) && (content.includes("dog") || content.includes("puppy"))) {
                dog = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random").then(res => res.json())
                client.sendMessage(message.from, await MessageMedia.fromUrl(dog.message, {unsafeMime: true}), {caption: 'OK, here is a photo of a dog/puppy.'})
            }
            if ((content.includes("give") || content.includes("send")) && content.includes("meme")) {
                meme = await fetch("https://meme-api.com/gimme/wholesomememes")
                  .then(response => response.json())
                client.sendMessage(message.from, await MessageMedia.fromUrl(meme.url, {unsafeMime: true}), {caption: meme.title})
            }
            if (content.includes("!chat"))
            {
                chatting = true
                console.log("chat start")
            }
        }
    });
    
    client.initialize();
```

Here's how starting a conversation is like:

Prompt: "Hi"

Response:

```cpp
;
    uint32_t esi;
    uint32_t edi;
    uint32_t ebp;
    uint32_t io_base;
    uint32_t eip;
    uint32_t cs;
    uint32_t eflags;
    uint32_t esp;
    uint32_t ss;
    uint32_t es;
    uint32_t ds;
    uint32_t fs;
    uint32_t gs;
    uint32_t ldt_selector;
    uint16_t t;
    uint16_t icharel_offset;
} _attribute_((packed)) TaskStateSegment;

/**
 * An interrupt gate holds the function to call when the interrupt is received.
 */
typedef struct {
    uint16_t offset_low;
    uint16_t segment_selector;
    uint8_t ist;
    uint8_t type_attr;
    uint16_t offset_middle;
    uint32_t offset_high;
    uint32_t reserved;
} _attribute_((packed)) InterruptGate;

/**
 * Represents any general descriptor in the system.
 * This could be a segment, task state, interrupt gate, or segment register.
 */
typedef struct {
    union {
        SegmentDescriptor segment;
        TaskStateSegment tss;
        InterruptGate interrupt_gate;
        uint32_t segment_register;
    };
} Descriptor;

/**
 * Represents a global descriptor.
 * This is basically just a descriptor with a tag denoting it's type.
 */
typedef struct {
    Descriptor descriptor;
    unsigned type;
} GDescriptor;

// Creates an interrupt gate to the given function.
InterruptGate interrupt_gate(void* handler, uint32_t ist);

// Creates a 64-bit TSS.
Descriptor tss_descriptor(uint32_t tss_size);
TaskSta
```

I have absolutely no idea what is going on but if somebody would like to help, it would be much appreciated!